# Unity dependency injection for UWP

Tags: unity-container, prism, uwp

I'm creating a UWP program using the PRISM 6 library from GitHub which has support for using Unity for dependency injection. However the current release of Unity (including the latest code in GitHub) has no mention of UWP support.

Does anyone know if the current Unity release is compatible with UWP projects?

Comment: Just try it? I'm curious why you would still want to use Unity with UWP...

Comment: @Herdo I like to use PRISM for its MVVM framework and I'm currently working on a fairly large cross-platform project which I've decided to base on UWP and Xamarin. With larger projects I find it much tidier to use PRISM's support of Unity dependency injection for passing services etc to the view models (not essential but a personal preference).

Comment: @Herdo I've tried adding the Win8.1 Unity PCL based package into the solution and it seems to work but there seems to be little info out there with regards to using Win8.1 PCL libraries with Win10 projects. Visual Studio has no Win10 PCL project templates? I'm worried about hitting compatibility issues using a PCL library written targeted to Win8.1 with the new .Net Native framework.

Answer (score 1):

The current Unity release (4.0.1) is compatible and working on UWP.

Edit: Due to project restructuring, samples have moved to a [separate repository](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows). One of the samples that is using Unity is the SplitView sample. Simply [derive your app](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/blob/master/SplitViewSample/SplitViewSample/App.xaml.cs) from `PrismUnityApplication`.

Comment: @dubstylee updated links, they changed due to restructuring.